# Group rows on one column and create nested array from another column

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, merge, grouping

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    [
        'name' => 'Umber',
        'reason' => 'No data',
        'id' => '12'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jakar',
        'reason' => 'Wrong format',
        'id' => '12'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Lane',
        'reason' => 'No data',
        'id' => '12'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jake',
        'reason' => 'Not found',
        'id' => '13'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jame',
        'reason' => 'Wrong name',
        'id' => '13'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'reason' => 'No data',
        'id' => '13'
    ]
];
```

What I want to do is group these elements in a table row if the same id value:

```
12 | No data, wrong format, No data
13 | Not found, Wrong name, No data
```

I know I have to use foreach for this one but the logic for grouping these elements in a single row is beyond me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I've started with this.

```
foreach($a as $value){
    echo $value['id'] . ' ' . $value['reason'];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First group elements to subarrays, then output each subarray:

```
$groups = [];
foreach($a as $value){
    $groups[$value['id']][] = $value['reason'];
}

foreach ($groups as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' | ' . implode(', ', $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps. It should help get you started:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($arrary as $arr) {
    $output[$arr['id']][] = $arr['reason'];
}

foreach ($output as $k => $v) {
    echo $k;
    echo implode(',', $v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, it is not necessary to declare an empty parent array before pushing data into it using square brace syntax.

Use the `id` values as keys and push the `reason` values into the group's array.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gNoTK))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['id']][] = $row['reason'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Or functional syntax:

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function($result, $row) {
            $result[$row['id']][] = $row['reason'];
            return $result;
        },
        []
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  12 => 
  array (
    0 => 'No data',
    1 => 'Wrong format',
    2 => 'No data',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Not found',
    1 => 'Wrong name',
    2 => 'No data',
  ),
)
```