# Filter Json Data By Category in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json file, which is being decoded in PHP. So my motive is to **categorized The Json by the key data from json.**

Let's see the json.

```
  [{
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1"
}]
```

My PHP code -

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('/myfile.json'), true);

$number = //here I want to count the articles or the data keys in json of specific category
for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++){
// What to put here ?
}
```

So i want to show articles link by categorizing them like -

```
Cat 1 --
 --- first article of cat 1 
 --- second article of cat 1
 --- third article of cat 1 
Cat 2 --
 --- first article of cat 2
 --- second article of cat 2
```

So how can i do in this way #PHP ?

Thanks for investing your time in my question. :)

Comment: first decode the json to a multidimensional array. Then sort the multidimensional array by key (there are existing on stackoverflow about how to do that). Then write a loop to go through the data and output it, detecting when there's a been a change of category by keeping a variable which holds the category value from the previous iteration, to compare to this one - this lets you decide whether to output a new category header or not.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the function [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) cannot handle this case. So you have to do it manually, a straight forward algorithm is:

```php
$json = '[{
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1"
}]';
$values = json_decode($json, true);

$res = [];
foreach ($values as $entry) {
  $category = $entry['category'];
  if (! array_key_exists($category, $res)) {
    $res[$category] = [];
  }
  $res[$category][] = $entry['article'];
}
```

After that the `$res` value hold the following data:

```
array(2) {
  ["Cat2"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
  }
  ["Cat1"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
  }
}
```

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVDNasMwDL7rKTRjiAOhZTs2Gzv0MUwIxlGXbEltbKc0jDx7FqdJGey4HaabpO9H@mxtp@n51dYW@Ls3Z3zBRH4CzsWUC41uiR2Q1SFYf9jv6ao629JOm45lN5RWgd6MGyLsqMITgzHD3yg8/gOFv/miSHLgF9X25OdcY7xlRdpUJJasMwyupzQH4G5ByCKHk3GkdI1iIyqPnM7BDelyD998ZvxtLpNtlMx8xOaE4gGVc2ooP2go6dr44MWdmGG0S9P1vdjI@7JYz0Ac4cdOFt9M11Si5whwUa6s@s6KRTufpi8)

Once you have the structure you can use PHP directly as a templating engine with something along

```php
<?php foreach($res as $category => $articles): ?>
  <h1><?= $category; ?></h1>
  <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
    <p><?= $article; ?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will output

```html
  <h1>Cat2</h1>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
  <h1>Cat1</h1>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912589/2943403

Comment: If this answer _is the answer_, then this page should be closed with [Group rows on one column and create nested array from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46178456/2943403)

Comment: Hello @AlexSmith you may want to look at what the [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) control structure is and how to use it.

Comment: @AlexSmith You can use `$res[$category][] = $entry` over `$res[$category][] = $entry['article']` in order to be able to access every key in your entry.

Comment: @AlexSmith I will not do the entire algorithm for you. I did answer to your question specifically and gave you hint on how to iterate. Now you have to understand each part of the code and adapt it to your need. Some questions to ask yourself: What a `foreach` do ? How to use it ? What does `<?=` mean ? How to iterate over a PHP array ? How to access an array value using its key ? What does `endforeach;` mean/do ? ...

Comment: The first `foreach` returns : the key (string) as `$category` and a list of `$articles` (which is an array or array). So what you may want to change is in the `foreach($articles as $article)`, where you can display more key-value pairs. You can use [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) in order to print the structure of your variable so you can see where are your data located.

Comment: You may need to adapt the data structure if you need to hold more data for the category. Currently it is laid out as `{categoryName: [articles]}` you may want to update it to something like `{categoryName: {categoryProp1, categoryProp2, articles: [articles]}}`

Comment: We have other duplicates that demonstrate how to build grouped subarrays.  I must have passed 10 of them before finding the suggested duplicate half a day ago.

Comment: @Alex if you want first level keys using categories, and then push rows of data into each group, we have many pages that demonstrate how to do this.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706456/2943403